# /bin/sh: /packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: No such file or directory Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode13

I have been stuck on this error for the past week going around all possible solutions I found online and nothing works. Can you please guide me on how I can solve this?

I am trying to build the app on Xcode and I am getting this error:

```
 /bin/sh -c /Users/rogeranttshibangu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
   /Runner-auyfpoaqieytnldpknrocgjqghkv/Build/Intermediates.noindex
   /Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh

 /bin/sh: /packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: 
   No such file or directory Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: Yes@PowermasterPrime I downgraded the Xcode version and it worked